Presto - Convert 2 String Fields to Date
I am looking for a processing friendly method to create a date field from 2 VARCHAR fields (year & month) such that the output is always the 1st of input month.
Output Format

%Y-%m-%d where %d is always 01

Current Fields

Field c_year (VARCHAR) in format 'FY##' (FY22, FY23, FY24, etc)
Field c_month (VARCHAR) in format 3 letter abbreviation (Jan, Feb, Mar)

I've put a few methods together but they seem run extremely slow.

DATE_PARSE with nested CONCAT(SUBSTR()) to get 4 digit year and CASE statement (12 checks) for month.
DATE_PARSE with LPAD and CASE etc

I imagine there's a better way then something silly like below:
SELECT date_parse(
           CONCAT('20', substr(c_year, 3, 2), '-', 
                  CASE c_month 
                      WHEN 'Jan' THEN '01'
                      WHEN 'Feb' THEN '02'
                      WHEN 'Mar' THEN '03'
                      WHEN 'Apr' THEN '04'
                      WHEN 'May' THEN '05'
                      WHEN 'Jun' THEN '06'
                      WHEN 'Jul' THEN '07'
                      WHEN 'Aug' THEN '08'
                      WHEN 'Sep' THEN '09'
                      WHEN 'Oct' THEN '10'
                      WHEN 'Nov' THEN '11'
                      WHEN 'Dec' THEN '12'
                  END,
                  '-01'),
           '%Y-%m-%d') AS period
FROM c_table


Postgres does not have DATEPARSE so you will need to be more specific about where and how you are doing this. Add as text update to question text.

Function is DATE_PARSE in Postgres @AdrianKlaver

There is no DATE_PARSE either in the community Postgres per Data formatting functions. There is to_date which I use in my answer below. You will need to add more information about your environment, in particular where you are getting Postgres from.

Your search for date_parse returned no hits., this function is unknown to PostgreSQL. Maybe you created it, but it's not a standard PostgreSQL function. If you created it, you should share the code and the internals with us to help you out.

@urdearboy no, this is Prsto/Trino function, there is no date_parse in the PostgreSQL but there is to_date.

select 
to_date(substring('FY22' from 3 for 2) || 'Jan' || '01', 'YYMonDD');
2022-01-01

See  Data formatting functions for more information on what the template patterns mean.

Just use standard parsing format literals - 'FY%y%b'. No need to concatenate 01 - it will be assumed by default, use FY literal in parse format string so it will be ignored in the source string, %y - 2 digit year, %b - abbreviated month name (docs):
-- sample data
WITH dataset(c_year, c_month) AS (
   values ('FY22', 'Jan'),
        ('FY23', 'Feb'),
        ('FY24', 'Mar'),
        ('FY24', 'Apr'),
        ('FY24', 'May'),
        ('FY24', 'Jun'),
        ('FY24', 'Jul'),
        ('FY24', 'Aug'),
        ('FY24', 'Sep'),
        ('FY24', 'Oct'),
        ('FY24', 'Nov'),
        ('FY24', 'Dec')
)

-- query
select date_parse(c_year || c_month, 'FY%y%b')
from dataset;

Output:
          _col0
-------------------------
 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000
 2023-02-01 00:00:00.000
 2024-03-01 00:00:00.000
 2024-04-01 00:00:00.000
 2024-05-01 00:00:00.000
 2024-06-01 00:00:00.000
 2024-07-01 00:00:00.000
 2024-08-01 00:00:00.000
 2024-09-01 00:00:00.000
 2024-10-01 00:00:00.000
 2024-11-01 00:00:00.000
 2024-12-01 00:00:00.000

Then you can transform the parsed date into any output format you need with date_format.
